# How do I add a custom attribute (such as a file hash) to a dropzone?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Using Dropzone 5.2.0.

I would like to add some custom attributes to a Dropzone when I load the page (that loads an existing file).

In my JS: On document ready, I do this:

```
var mydropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone", {
        init: function () {
            var existingFile = getExistingFile();
            var self = this;
            if (existingFile != null) {
                var size = existingFile.Length;
                var name = existingFile.Name;
                existingDropzoneFile = { name: name, size: size, type: 'txt' };
                self.emit("addedfile", existingDropzoneFile);
            }
        }
    });
```

How do I add something like adding a custom attribute of "hash" and displaying it in the html? Or foo:'bar' eve?

```
var mydropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone", {
        init: function () {
            var existingFile = getExistingFile();
            var self = this;
            if (existingFile != null) {
                var size = existingFile.Length;
                var name = existingFile.Name;
                var hash = existingFile.Hash;
                existingDropzoneFile = { name: name, size: size, type: 'txt', hash:hash, foo:'bar' };
                self.emit("addedfile", existingDropzoneFile);
            }
        }
    });
```

Do I create my own template and assign this value to the template?

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
  <div class="dz-details">
    <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
    <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>
    <div class="dz-hash" data-dz-hash></div>
    <div class="dz-foo" data-dz-foo></div>
    <img data-dz-thumbnail />
  </div>
  <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
  <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>
  <div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>
  <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
</div>
```